# Find all $x^6 \pmod {17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all $a$ such that $x^6 \equiv a\pmod {17}$ (not including $0$)

First I thought that we could look at $y^2 \equiv a \pmod {17}$, where $y=x^3$.

Then, by Euler's criterion, it must be that:

$$a^{\frac{17 -1}{2}} \equiv a^8 \equiv 1 \pmod {17}$$

I could develop it to

$$a^8 -1 \equiv 0 \pmod {17} \implies\\ (a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)\equiv 0\pmod {17}$$

I'm not sure it's the right way. Could you guide me please?

By the way, we are not familiar with $\text {ind}$

Comment: Since your problem begins with “Find all $a$ such that”, I would expect that what follws is a propostion depending on $a$. But it isn't. So, what does the problem *mean*?

Comment: Hmm that's just me rephrasing the original question which is: "Find all $x^{6} \pmod {17}$ (excluding $0$)"

Comment: Since $17$ is quite small, can't you just calculate $x^6$ for $x=0,1,...,16$ ?

Comment: @zwim, Maybe. I just thought there's more than that (a quicker/elegant way)

Comment: I did the calculation and the reachable values are $0,1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16$ and non-reachable $3,5,6,7,10,11,12,14$. I do not see a particularly "nice" pattern there that would indicate a shortcut to find these values.

Comment: Noting that $(-x)^6 = x^6$ halves the work. Noting that $\gcd(3,17-1) = 1$ reduces it to finding the quadratic residues.

Comment: @DanielFischer. could you elaborate more about finding the quadratic residues? I think that's the purpose of this exercise actually (we just learned it)

Comment: Brute force is easiest and fastest.  Since cubing is an automorphism of the multiplicative group, you can ignore the factor of $3$ and just work with squares, but that doesn't help all that much.  Well, if you are doing it with paper and pencil then squaring is certainly easier than raising to the sixth power.

Comment: I don't know a real shortcut. But you know how many quadratic residues there are, and you know that the product of two residues is a residue. So when you've found a nontrivial ($\neq 1$) residue $r$, you know that $r^2, r^3,\dotsc$ are residues too. If you're lucky that gives them all at the first hit. Here, if you know that $2$ is a residue, it follows that $4,8,16,15,13,9$ are residues too, together with the trivial $1$ and the initial $2$ you have them all.

Comment: Since $\gcd(6,16)=2$, the set of $6$-th powers is the same as the set of squares.

Comment: @lhf, Could you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 4):

The group of nonzero residues modulo $17$ is not merely cyclic, it is cyclic of order $16$, which is relatively prime to $3$. This means that every residue has a unique cube root. As you very perceptively recognized, solving $x^6=a$ is the same as solving $y^2=a$; but you didn’t realize that given such a $y$, there is *exactly one* $x$ with $x^3=y$.

It follows, as @lhf pointed out in a comment, that the sixth powers in $\Bbb F_{17}^*$ are exactly the squares in this group.

Comment: Lubin, could you explain why there's exactly one $x$ with $x^3 = y$? In other words if $R = \{1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16\}$ then $R^3 = R$ (where $R^3 = \{ r^3 \mid r\in R\})$.

Comment: Sure, easy: $3\cdot11=33\equiv1\pmod{16}$, so that if you give me $y$ for which you want a cube root, then I give you $y^{11}$, because $(y^{11})^3=y\cdot(y^{16})^2=y$, since $y^{16}=1$. And if $x^3=\xi^3$, then $(x/\xi)^3=1$, so that $x/\xi=1$, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

I got $$a\in\{0,1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16\}$$ and it occurs for
$$x\in\{0,1,5,8,6,7,2,3,4\}$$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

For all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $x\equiv y\pmod{17}$, then $x^6\equiv y^6\pmod{17}$, so it's enough to check one number from each residue class. Take the residue classes $0,1\ldots,16,17$. We obtain:
$$a\in\{0,1,2,4,9,13,15,16\}$$

---

There is a quick way to find out how many possible values of $a$ there are. Since $17$ is prime, there exists a primitive root modulo $17$, say $r$. Now, suppose we have some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with:
$$(r^a)^6\equiv (r^b)^6\pmod 17$$
or, using Fermat's little theorem:
$$16\mid 6(a-b)\iff8\mid a-b$$
It follows that there are $8$ possible residues.

Answer (score 2):

The multiplicative group of the residues $\not = 0$ is cyclic. So there exists a generating element (called a primitive root) 
$\alpha.$ So the requested numbers are 
$$\{\alpha^2,\alpha^4,\alpha^6,\alpha^8,\alpha^{10},\alpha^{12},\alpha^{14},\alpha^{16}\}.$$
The following residues are primitive roots 
$$\{\alpha,\alpha^3,\alpha^5,\alpha^7,\alpha^{9},\alpha^{11},\alpha^{13},\alpha^{15}\}.$$ So if you select an arbitrary residue different from $0$ you have a chance of $0.5$ that it is a primitive root. A selected element is a primitive root if $\alpha^8 \not=1$. Actually it is sufficient to find $\alpha^2$. This is a number $\beta$ such that $b^4\not=1$ but $b^8=1.$ The residue $2$ is such a $\beta$, so 
$$2, 4, 8, 16 \;(=-1), -2, -4, -8,-16\;(=1)$$ are the requested numbers.